# Advance XMPP Connection - SASLAuthentication, socketFactory

Tags: xmpp, spring-integration, smack

I want to create XMPP connection with security, I tried this

```
<bean id="xmppConnection" class="o.s.i.xmpp.XmppConnectionFactoryBean">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration">
            <constructor-arg value="myServiceName"/>
            <property name="truststorePath" value="..."/>
            <property name="socketFactory" ref="..."/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

dependencies

```
dependencies {

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-xmpp:4.3.8.RELEASE")

    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

But class `o.s.i.xmpp.XmppConnectionFactoryBean` not found. Do I need to include any other dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is abbreviated because of formatting for the documentation. The actual class name is

```
org.springframework.integration.xmpp.config.XmppConnectionFactoryBean
```

This is explained [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/_conventions_in_this_book.html).

> **1. Conventions in this Book**
>
> In some cases, to aid formatting, when specifying long fully-qualified class names, we shorten the package `org.springframework` to `o.s` and `org.springframework.integration` to `o.s.i`, such as with `o.s.i.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationFactory`.

If you use IDE content assist (eclipse, IDEA) when typing class names, it will complete the package for you.